# Magento 2 - Getting order information

Tags: product, magento2, module, orders, api

I'm working on creating a file that I can use to send any orders received on a particular day via a post API call. Magento's code appears to have changed dramatically now so I'm finding getting started a little difficult.

Is there any good documentation available that would show how to perform basic tasks such as getting recent order information, getting an image location based on a products ID, getting a custom attribute value of a product etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the official [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html). Magento 2 has a new concept of [service contracts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html), basically it is an API which you should use in custom modules. Not sure if there is a complete list of services available, but you can just look for necessary service inside of `Magento/<RelatedModuleName>/Api`, where `<RelatedModuleName>` is in your case "Sales", "Catalog".

E.g.

- for getting filtered list of orders
  `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::getList`
- for product
  data `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::get`
- for
  product images
  `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface::getList`